# Что не так происходит при  использование explode?

Tags: массивы, php

```
<?$lines = file('file.txt',  FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES | FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
print_r($lines);
$res = explode('=', $lines);
print_r($res)
?>
```

файл содержит:
    version = ‘1.3.15’

```
source.id = ‘1’

source.path = ‘some/path’

login.remember = ‘1’

login.name = ‘userName’

login.password = ‘password’

awful.layout = ‘split’

awful.layout.suit = ‘tile’
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если хотите так, то можно попробовать

```
<?php
$lines = file('file.txt',  FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES | FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
print_r($lines);

for($i=0, $res=array(); isset($lines[$i]); $i++)
   if(trim($lines[$i]) != '')
     $res[] = explode('=', $lines[$i]);
print_r($res);
?>
```

Comment: #node_pro
    Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in C:\Apache2.2\htdocs\proba.php on line 6

Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in C:\Apache2.2\htdocs\proba.php on line 6


Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in C:\Apache2.2\htdocs\proba.php on line 6

Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in C:\Apache2.2\htdocs\proba.php on line 6
Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] => [10] => [11] => [12] => [13] => [14] => )

Comment: Исправил в ответе

Answer (score 3):

Второй параметр функции `explode` должен быть строкой, а не массивом. Для чтения содержимого файла в строку используйте функцию `file_get_contents`. Или применяйте функцию `explode` к каждому элементу возвращаемого массива в цикле.

- [explode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php)
- [file](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file.php)
- [file_get_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php)